# postgresql - on update trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to do on update trigger, which will be automatically updating current_timestamp only when column updated_date is not openly updated.

function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dba.update_stamp_pc() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'NEW.updated_date: %', NEW.updated_date;
    RAISE NOTICE 'OLD.updated_date: %', OLD.updated_date;
    IF NEW.updated_date=OLD.updated_date OR NEW.updated_date is null then
        NEW.updated_date := current_timestamp;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

Checks:

```
aaa=> insert into dba.pc_test1 values(7);
INSERT 0 1
aaa=> select order_id,created_date,updated_date from dba.pc_test1 where order_id=7;
 order_id |         created_date          | updated_date 
----------+-------------------------------+--------------
    7 | 2022-02-23 10:01:23.142326+00 | 
(1 row)
aaa=> update dba.pc_test1 set order_id=7 where order_id=7;
NOTICE:  NEW.updated_date: <NULL>
NOTICE:  OLD.updated_date: <NULL>
UPDATE 1
aaa=> select order_id,created_date,updated_date from dba.pc_test1 where order_id=7;
 order_id |         created_date          |        updated_date         
----------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------
    7 | 2022-02-23 10:01:23.142326+00 | 2022-02-23 10:02:04.5021+00
(1 row)
aaa=> \d dba.pc_test1
                            Table "dba.pc_test1"
Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |         Default         
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------
 order_id     | bigint                      |           | not null | 
 created_date | timestamp(6) with time zone |           | not null | 
 created_by   | character varying(50)       |           | not null | 
 updated_date | timestamp(6) with time zone |           |          | 
 updated_by   | character varying(50)       |           |          | NULL::character varying
Triggers:
    insert_pc_test1 BEFORE INSERT ON dba.pc_test1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION dba.insert_stamp_pc()
    update_pc_test1 BEFORE UPDATE ON dba.pc_test1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION dba.update_stamp_pc()

aaa=> update dba.pc_test1 set order_id=7 where order_id=7;
NOTICE:  NEW.updated_date: 2022-02-23 10:02:04.5021+00
NOTICE:  OLD.updated_date: 2022-02-23 10:02:04.5021+00
UPDATE 1
aaa=> select order_id,created_date,updated_date from dba.pc_test1 where order_id=7;
 order_id |         created_date          |         updated_date          
----------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
   7 | 2022-02-23 10:01:23.142326+00 | 2022-02-23 10:03:03.571949+00
(1 row)
aaa=> update dba.pc_test1 set order_id=7,updated_date='2000-01-01' where order_id=7;
NOTICE:  NEW.updated_date: 2000-01-01 00:00:00+00
NOTICE:  OLD.updated_date: 2022-02-23 10:03:03.571949+00
UPDATE 1
aaa=> select order_id,created_date,updated_date from dba.pc_test1 where order_id=7;
 order_id |         created_date          |      updated_date      
----------+-------------------------------+------------------------
7 | 2022-02-23 10:01:23.142326+00 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00+00
(1 row)
aaa=> update dba.pc_test1 set order_id=7,updated_date='2000-01-01' where order_id=7;
NOTICE:  NEW.updated_date: 2000-01-01 00:00:00+00
NOTICE:  OLD.updated_date: 2000-01-01 00:00:00+00
UPDATE 1
aaa=> select order_id,created_date,updated_date from dba.pc_test1 where order_id=7;
 order_id |         created_date          |         updated_date          
----------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
   7 | 2022-02-23 10:01:23.142326+00 | 2022-02-23 10:03:45.473659+00
(1 row)
aaa=>
```

In the last case, updated_date should have value '2000-01-01 00:00:00+00', but because inside the database such value already exists then the current_timestamp is inserted. How to fix it?

Comment: try this : `IF NEW.updated_date IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.updated_date OR NEW.updated_date is null then NEW.updated_date := current_timestamp`

Comment: unfortunately, do not work:
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dba.update_stamp_pc() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'NEW.updated_date: %', NEW.updated_date;
RAISE NOTICE 'OLD.updated_date: %', OLD.updated_date;
IF NEW.updated_date IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.updated_date OR NEW.updated_date is null then 
    NEW.updated_date := current_timestamp;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;`

Comment: in this way it will always update this column:
`aaa=> update dba.pc_test1 set order_id=7,updated_date='2000-01-01' where order_id=7;
NOTICE:  NEW.updated_date: 2000-01-01 00:00:00+00
NOTICE:  OLD.updated_date: 2022-02-23 11:12:37.333432+00
UPDATE 1
aaa=> select order_id,created_date,updated_date from dba.pc_test1 where order_id=7;
 order_id |         created_date          |         updated_date          
----------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
        7 | 2022-02-23 10:01:23.142326+00 | 2022-02-23 11:13:11.677408+00
 `

Comment: Do not put your code in the comments, add as update to your question and in a comment indicate you have made changes.

Comment: According to your description of what you want it should be: `IF NEW.updated_date is null THEN ...`

Comment: thank you for this @AdrianKlaver, not sure if I understand you properly, I have there such condition, but it is only for the case for first update when updated_date column is null. Please notice that each time when this column (updated_date) is not updated  `NEW.updated_date` is the same as `OLD.updated_date`

Comment: The issue is that in Postgres an `UPDATE` is basically  delete of `OLD` values and an insert of `NEW` values. That means there will always be a `NEW.updated_date` even if you do not include it in the `UPDATE` statement.  There is no way to distinguish if was supplied by the user or rolled over into `NEW` from  `OLD`. You would have to add some sort of 'flag' field to the table to catch the difference e.g. user_update boolean. Another option would be to use my suggestion and explicitly do `updated_date=null` when you want the timestamp set to `current_timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample trigger function and tested it, 100% working.
Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_test_table() 
returns trigger
language plpgsql
AS $$
begin
    
    if new.action_date = old.action_date or new.action_date is null then
        new.action_date := current_timestamp;
    end if;
   
    return new;
end;
$$;


CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_test_table
BEFORE UPDATE
ON test_table
FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_test_table();
```

Comment: the probem is with this update:
`update dba.pc_test1 set order_id=7,updated_date='2000-01-01' where order_id=7;`
Please run it twice, then you will realise that instead to have this 2000-01-01, there will be current timestamp.